# Responsive CSS image not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, slider

I'm trying to implement this responsive css image slider, but it doesn't seem to working on mobile devices at all.. [Demo review](http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pres/ehKpi)

It works when I visit Codepen page on my phone, but on my url it just hangs on the first image for some reason..(only on mobile, works fine on desktop) And I've tried different browsers on different phones..

Now the code is exactly the same as on codepen, there's no tags clashing or anything like that and it's fairly simple.

Is there something else you need to add to make it mobile friendly? I can't imagine what, because it's just CSS..

So, maybe I need another pair of eyes, but I'm just not getting what could be affecting it??

So here's the code:

HTML

```
<div id="slider">
<figure>
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/taj-mahal.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ibiza.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/ankor-wat.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/austin-fireworks.jpg" alt="">
</figure>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes slidy {
0% { left: 0%; }
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: what mobile browser are you using? what mobile phone? ios? android?

Comment: both ios and android, safari, chrome and the default android browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually in these cases, the culprit is viewport meta tag.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Have you added this, in your webpage?

Comment: Yes, I've had that... I've copied yours to try again, thinking I might have had a typo, but still no luck... Are there any other viewport tags that might need to be set?

Comment: @user3520281 Not any, am aware of. If you can share your website link, I might be able to help.

Comment: hey, I made another quick test page.. http://brobo.com.au/test/test.html have a look if you can on yours.. its strange

Comment: @user3520281 sorry for the late reply, Is the URL still valid? I couldn't find a slider there.

Comment: hi mate, no the link won't be valid anymore. I didn't end up figuring it out, but I'll manage without it.. Thanks for your help!